# Including the (0,0) point in a linear regression in R

Tags: r, regression

I have run a simple linear regression in R with two variables and got the following relation:

y = 30000+1.95x

Which is reasonably fair. My only concern is that, practically the (0,0) point should be included in the model.

Is there any math help I can get please ?

---

[image: Data set]

I needed to post the data somehow... and here it is. This will give a better approach to the problem now.

There are more such data sets available. This is data collected for a marketing strategy.

The objective is to obtain a relation between sales and spend so that we can predict the spend amount that we need in order to obtain a certain amount of sales.

All help will be appreciated.

Comment: Do you want to add the (0,0) point as a data point in the regression, or force the fitted curve to pass through the origin?

Comment: As a data point.. But it doesn't seem to be anywhere in line with other data then...

Comment: Would you please post a link to the data?

Comment: Month                 Spend Campaign Sales
Aug 17        120499 327341
Sept 17       168666 548424
Oct 17         334308 978437
Nov 17 311963 885522
Dec 17 275592 696238
Jan 18 405845 1268859
Feb 18  399824 1054429
Mar 18  343622 1193147
Apr 18   619030 1118420.13
May 18   541674      985816.35
Jun 18   701460 1263009.84
Jul 18   957681 1960920.65
Aug 18   479050 1240943.9
sept 18   552718 1821106.45
oct 18    633517 1959944.43
Nov 18 527424 2351679.84
Dec 18 1050231 2419749.31
Jan 19  583889 2104677.16
Feb 19   322356 1373471.1

Comment: @JamesPhillips I have collected the data , I do not have a link to the data, I will try to post it in a better legible manner

Comment: This is good enough for me, thanks - looking at it now.

Comment: Please see my comments with graphs below, as comments do not allow graphs I posted in the form of an answer.

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "the(0,0) point should be included in the model"

Comment: It means that when the amount spend is 0, the sales amount should also be 0. Practically. Otherwise the relation is linear - that is very clear...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to include the point (0,0) in your regression line this would mean setting the intercept to zero. 
In R you can achieve this by

```
mod_nointercept <- lm(y ~ 0 + x)
```

In this model only beta is fitted. And alpha (i.e. the intercept is set to zero).

Comment: I had asked in the question's comments if the (0,0) point should be used as a data point or if the curve should pass through the origin, the reply of the OP will affect your answer.

Comment: @Cettt Thank you for the input.

Comment: I have given the data set. IS there any luck as yet?

Comment: This was the best solution that I could find for the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This is not an answer, but rather a comment with graphics.

I converted the month data to "elapsed months", starting with 1 as the first month, then 2, then 3 etc. This allowed me to view the data in 3D, and as you can see from the 3D scatterplot below, both Spend and Sales are related to the number of months that have passed. I also scaled the financial data in thousands so I could more easily read the plots.

I fit the data to a simple flat surface equation of the form "z = f(x,y)" as shown below, as this equation was suggested to me by the scatterplot. My fit of this data gave me the equation

```
Sales (thousands) = a + b * Months + c * Spend(thousands)
```

with fitted parameters

```
a = 2.1934871882483066E+02
b = 6.3389747441412403E+01
c = 1.0011902575903093E+00
```

for the following data:

```
Month Spend Sales

1 120.499 327.341
2 168.666 548.424
3 334.308 978.437
4 311.963 885.522
5 275.592 696.238
6 405.845 1268.859
7 399.824 1054.429
8 343.622 1193.147
9 619.030 1118.420
10 541.674 985.816
11 701.460 1263.009
12 957.681 1960.920
13 479.050 1240.943
14 552.718 1821.106
15 633.517 1959.944
16 527.424 2351.679
17 1050.231 2419.749
18 583.889 2104.677
19 322.356 1373.471
```

[image: scatterplot]

[image: surface]

Comment: Thank you so much for this effort. But ideally, the month does not play any role in the sales at all...

Comment: I understand. If it is "month 20" (so that you have the above data) and in a business meeting the question is asked, "If we spend X dollars next month, what are expected sales?" with this model you could both give an accurate answer, and prove that accuracy. Demonstrating this was part of the reason for my reply.

Comment: Yes, it is a good point somehow...  i will try to fit it in and see if the prediction works for other data sets

Comment: No luck :( ... The relationship is linear and is very clear... the only problem coming that when spend amount is 0, sales should be 0... which is not being satisfied by the model...

Comment: Could it be that spend and sales have an additional, as-yet-unmodeled time lag component as people think over purchase decisions? That is, does this month's spend affect future sales? That would affect the (0,0) data point's accuracy such that a zero spend this month would not directly produce zero sales this month.

Comment: It is very unlikely that the spend of current month will affect the sales of next month. I have centred the datasets by subtracting the mean from both variables and this gives a regression passing through 0,0. But the coefficient doesn't change thus giving high differences from real data.